# php, how can I update ini file?

Tags: php, ini

I have an PlatformIO ini file:

```
; PlatformIO Project Configuration File
;
;   Build options: build flags, source filter
;   Upload options: custom upload port, speed and extra flags
;   Library options: dependencies, extra library storages
;   Advanced options: extra scripting
;
; Please visit documentation for the other options and examples
; http://docs.platformio.org/page/projectconf.html

[env:d1_mini]
platform = qsprgssif2266
board = d1_mini
framework = arduino
lib_deps = ArduinoJson, PubSubClient
upload_port = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

**I want to add new string to lib_deps everytime I add new value with html input.**

like this:

```
<form>
<input value="newphpvalue" />
</form

lib_deps = ArduinoJson, PubSubClient,{newphpvalue},{newphpvalue2}
```

*I know this can be archived with using php write_ini_file, but exactly how?*

I also looked for some libraries(built in functions) for adding values to ini file.
I found IniFile-master, but with this I cant add new value,it writes to older one, **so is there any other libraries for doing this?**

Comment: use the function `ini_set(key, value);` Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php

Comment: @C0dekid That function has nothing to do with the question at hand, that only sets a runtime value for a key in php.ini

Comment: @C0dekid that's just for the `php.ini`